# Spring Cloud Stream disable retry

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, spring-retry, spring-cloud-function

I'm using Spring cloud stream with spring cloud function with reactive approach. My binder is RabbitMQ.
By definition maxAttempts property is the number of times that a message can be processed (that's what I interpret)
From: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties

> maxAttempts:
> If processing fails, the number of attempts to process the message (including the first). Set to 1 to disable retry.
> Default: 3.

The problem is my application with this (default) configuration always processed the message 4 times. And now I want to disable the retry, so I set max-attempts=1 and the message is always processed 2 times.
I have already tried to set `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.requeue-rejected=false` although is the default.

Any clue on how can I get my message processed just once?

Thanks.

Comment: This makes no sense; with `maxAttempts=1`, the binder does not add a `RetryTemplate` to the channel adapter so no retries will occur. Something else is going on. Please provide a small, complete, example that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the reply. I have created a small project demonstrating the issue at https://github.com/moreirajo/spring-retry-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoxton.SR1 is very old

I can see why it was retried with those versions; I updated your example to the latest versions and it is only delivered once now...

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>retry-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>retry-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

I don't know which version it was fixed in.

Comment: Thanks Gary, it's true that updating the spring cloud version solve the problem, so I will accept the answer. What I didn't mention is that I have others dependencies in my project that fails with most recent versions. For example https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/409. So there is any workaround that I could do to disable the retry system and still stay in SR1?

Comment: There is not a work around with SR1 because retry (wrongly) hard-coded to retry for `maxAttempts` (instead of `maxAttempts - 1`). i.e. `maxAttempts` is being treated as the number of retries instead of the total attempts including the original, and you cannot set `maxAttempts=0`.